# String continuation across multiple lines, no newline characters

Tags: r, newline, word-wrap, rodbc, end-of-line

Am using the RODBC library to bring data into R.  I have a long query that I want to pass a variable to, much like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330072/pass-r-variable-to-rodbcs-sqlquery) SO user.

Problem is that R interprets the whitespace/carriage returns in my query as a newline `'\n'`.

The accepted solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329962/split-code-over-multiple-lines-in-an-r-script) suggests to simply break up the text into chunks and then `paste()` together - which works, but ideally I'd like to keep the whitespace intact - makes it easier to test/verify the behavior of the query over in the database before pasting into R.

In other languages I'm familiar with there's a simple line continuation character - indeed, several of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6330066/561698) on the accepted answer are looking for an approach similar to python's `\`.

I found an aside to a workaround using `strwrap` deep in the bowels of an R discussion lists, so in the interest of making the internet better I will post it here.  However, if someone can point the direction toward a more elegant/straightforward solution, I will happily accept your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
query <- gsub(pattern='\\s',replacement="",x=query)
```

Comment: This works. What exactly is `\\s` and is there a place to find more info (I tried the obvious `?"\\s"` but I suspect regular expressions are not provided in help

Comment: @user5783745 the [manual page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) provides more info.  `\s` is the whitespace class in unix-style extended regex.  The backspace has to be quoted, hence `\\s`.

Answer (score 18):

I don't know if you will find this helpful or not, but I have eventually gravitated towards keeping my SQL separate from my R scripts. Keeping the query in my R script, except for very very short ones, I find gets unreadable very quickly.

These days, I tend to keep queries that are more than a single line in their own separate .sql file. Then I can keep them nice and formatted and readable in a nice text editor, and read them into R as needed via something like this:

```
read_sql <- function(path){
    stopifnot(file.exists(path))
    sql <- readChar(path,nchar = file.info(path)$size)
    sql
}
```

For binding parameters into the queries, I just keep a `%s` where the parameter will go in the .sql file, and then add in the parameters in R using `sprintf`.

I've been much happier this way, as I was finding that cluttering up my R scripts with really long `paste` statements and multi-line character objects was making my code really hard to read.

Answer (score 13):

R's `strwrap` will destroy whitespace, including newline characters, per the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strwrap.html).

Essentially, you can get the desired behavior by initially letting R introduce line breaks/newline `\n`s, and then immediately stripping them out.

```
#make query using PASTE
query_1 <- paste("SELECT map.ps_studentid 
      ,students.first_name || ' ' || students.last_name AS full_name
      ,map.testritscore
      ,map.termname
      ,map.measurementscale
FROM map$comprehensive_with_growth map
JOIN students 
  ON map.ps_studentid = students.id
WHERE map.termname = '",map_term,"'", sep='')

#remove newline characters introduced above.  
#width is an arbitrary big number-
#it just needs to be longer than your string.
query_1 <- strwrap(query_1, width=10000, simplify=TRUE)

#execute the query 
map_njask <- sqlQuery(XE, query_1)
```

Comment: That's nice, thanks! Should assign the output of `strwrap` back to `query_1` above, though.

Comment: Why not try `gsub("\n", '', ...)` , as John Andrews suggests below? Works for me.

Comment: @Audrey that's definitely cleaner.  changing the accepted answer to John's.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using sprintf to get variable substitution, and then replacing all newlines and whitespace.

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684342/1165112) to a similar question for details.