# how to break up long functions over multiple lines in R?

Tags: r

I'm BRAND NEW to all coding so "like you're explaining it to an 8 year old" answers please!

I have created a function that trails off the right side of my typing area (top left box in RStudio).

```
MySamplingDistribution <- function(myVector)

{
return(mean(replicate(100, mean(sample(myVector, size=20, replace=TRUE)), simplify=TRUE)))
}
```

It runs fine in that format, but when I try to break it up on to 2 lines, like my book tells me:

```
MySamplingDistribution <- function(myVector)

{
return(mean(replicate(100, mean(sample(myVector,+
size=20, replace=TRUE)), simplify=TRUE)))
}
```

I get this error:

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I'm sure it's just some issue with spaces or tabs or something but I've attempted enough combinations and browsed enough forums to be asking here. I've just installed and am using RStudio, if that makes a difference.

THX!

Comment: Remove the `+`. That's something the interpreter adds to denote code you have tried to run which is syntactically incomplete.

Comment: You should use an IDE (try Rstudio, ESS, Eclipse+StatET, in no particular order). It will indent code for you.

Comment: You can add an arbitrary amount of white space (or line breaks) after any `,`, `(`, `[`, `{`, amongst other characters. You can only add a line break after an unquoted `+` if the `+` is appropriate in the context (e.g. if you are performing an addition)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split code over multiple lines in an R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329962/split-code-over-multiple-lines-in-an-r-script)