# What does the "+" sign mean at the start of a line?

Tags: r, rstudio

What does the "+" sign mean in RStudio? Most lines start with `>` but others start with `+` (for continue line I think). I'm reading along in a book and it is writing arguments for functions on separate lines but I'm not sure how to do that.

Or sometimes I see code like

```
> mtcars %>%
+   group_by(cyl) %>%
+   summarize(mean(mpg))
```

Comment: It means you haven't finished the line yet. Missing brackets/parentheses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split code over multiple lines in an R script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329962/split-code-over-multiple-lines-in-an-r-script)

Answer (score 6):

As Richard Scriven stated, `+`  is shown at the start of continuation lines.  That is, when you pressed Enter without completing the R expression that you were typing.  This is the case in all R IDEs (R GUI, Architect, etc.), not just RStudio.

The value that is printed is a global option: you can retrieve it using `getOption("continue")` and change it with the `options` function.  I keep it set to spaces in order to make it easier to copy code from the command line to a script.

```
options(continue = "  ")
```

On Stack Overflow and other forums, most people will edit the posted code to remove the start-of-line characters (`>` on the first line of a command, `+` on additional lines for the same command). But sometimes you will encounter code without those symbols already removed - you will need to remove them yourself before copy/pasting the code into a script or your R console.