# Continue a file path in the next line in R

Tags: r, r-markdown

When a render this script with the RMarkdown, the path of a file **exceeds the limit** of the PDF.

```
df_reserva = read_excel('E:/OneDrive/FACULDADE/Semestre 6/Métodos Quantitativos Aplicados a Políticas Públicas e Sociais/Trabalho Final/Bases de Dados/forms.xlsx')
```

I want to add some **line breaks**, so the **code** looks like this

```
df_reserva = read_excel('E:/OneDrive/FACULDADE/Semestre 6/    
Métodos Quantitativos Aplicados a Políticas Públicas e Sociais/    
Trabalho Final/Bases de Dados/forms.xlsx')
```

Any tips here?

Comment: Do you want to add line breaks? Use ```\\``` or ```\newline```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `file.path()`. For instance:

```r
df_reserva = read_excel(file.path('E:/OneDrive/FACULDADE/Semestre 6',
                                  'Métodos Quantitativos Aplicados a Políticas Públicas e Sociais',
                                  'Trabalho Final/Bases de Dados/forms.xlsx')
```

If you use R > 4.1.0 you can also use basepipe (`|>`) to make it more readable by avoiding nested parenthesis:

```r
file.path('E:/OneDrive/FACULDADE/Semestre 6',
          'Métodos Quantitativos Aplicados a Políticas Públicas e Sociais',
          'Trabalho Final/Bases de Dados/forms.xlsx') |>
    read_excel() -> df_reserva
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
p1 <- 'E:/OneDrive/FACULDADE/Semestre 6/'
p2 <- 'Métodos Quantitativos Aplicados a Políticas Públicas e Sociais/'
p3 <- 'Trabalho Final/Bases de Dados/forms.xlsx'
df_reserva <- read_excel(paste0(p1, p2, p3))
```

Comment: It works! But is there any possibility to do it like in Python, where we can use "\" to continue on the next line?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think so since the the backslash and new line will be included in the string. See [Split code over multiple lines in an R script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329962/split-code-over-multiple-lines-in-an-r-script) for some other approaches.